# Linux: grab audio from a video clip

Tags: linux, video, audio, conversion, extract

I'd like to take audio track from a video clip in FLV container and save it to something playable by portable music players. Are there any easy to use tools for that? I know how to do that using console tools (mplayer+lame/oggenc), but I'd like to get something clickable, preferably for GNOME.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anything you find is just going to defer to the command line tools, so unless you have a burning need for click-and-point, they'll do fine. If you *do* need click-and-point then it's probably easiest to throw together a GUI in Python or the like that just drives the command line tools (or pay someone else to do so).

Comment: This is for a person who does not speak shellish. I considered making a simple script, but hoped someone did that earlier. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Konverter](http://www.kraus.tk/projects/konverter/)

> Konverter is a KDE MEncoder frontend
>   for easy video conversions, scaling
>   and cropping. Just select any common
>   input format and select your favourite
>   output format, codec and size (cropped
>   or scaled). It also features
>   videosplitting, videomerging and a
>   preview mode. Just simple and powerful
>   :-)

I can't tell whether it supports audio extraction, but it seems fairly complete, so it seems likely it does.

Comment: It seems dead (last release in 2005). I'll check it later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Avidemux for this.  It works pretty well.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to save audio in an .OGG or .MP3 format. Also I couldn't find a way to disable video. Is it possible with `avidemux`?

Comment: Oh, crap, sorry, I haven't been checking Superuser lately.  Yes, it should be.  It's in Audio->Save...